# checking if record exists in Sqlite + C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, c#-4.0

I'm trying to check if a record in a table already exists.

How could I do that?

I already wrote the following code:

```
string dbName = "Data Source=searchindex.db";
SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(dbName);
con.Open();
SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(con);

// If this sql request return false
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT rowid FROM wordlist WHERE word='word'"; 
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

// then add record in table
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO wordlist(word) VALUES ('word')";
```

Comment: i cannot figure out what you're asking about here!

Comment: You could add a " where not exists .... " condition to the insert statement.

Comment: `If this sql request return false... then add record in table`  Your goal is to prevent duplicates, inserting the word only if it does not exist, right?

Answer (score 22):

To check if that record exists you could simplify your code

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT count(*) FROM wordlist WHERE word='word'"; 
int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
if(count == 0)
{
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO wordlist(word) VALUES ('word')"; 
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

[ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) will return the first column on the first row returned by your query.
(The link is for SqlServer, but it is identical for SQLite, because the SQLiteCommand should implement the [IDbCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt2afddc.aspx) interface)

Another approach to use is the following

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO wordlist (word) 
                   SELECT ('word')
                   WHERE NOT EXISTS 
                       (SELECT 1 FROM wordlist WHERE word = 'word');";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This is even better because you use a single query and not two (albeit the difference in a local db should be minimal)

Comment: Fantastic answer to OP's question.  My search is over.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **sqlite-net-pcl** you could write the following.

I have a base class for several tables and in it, I have a RowExists method. 
The relevant source code looks as follows:

```
public abstract class BaseSQLiteAccess
{
    protected SQLiteConnection _databaseConnection;
    protected String TableName { get; set; }

    //...

    protected bool RowExists(int id) 
    {
        bool exists = false;
        try
        {
            exists = _databaseConnection.ExecuteScalar<bool>("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM " + TableName + " WHERE ID=?)", id);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log database error
            exists = false;
        }
        return exists;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        insert into wordlist(word)
        select 'foo' 
        where not exists ( select 1 from wordlist where word = 'foo')
```

Comment: Thank you Tim. My goal originally was to check if there is a record exist in the table, then extract the last rowid, otherwise add a record in the table and extract the last rowid. Why you use (1) in sql request insead of (*) ?

Comment: `...otherwise add a record in the table and extract the last rowid`. Your code above was not extracting the last rowid if the word did not exist yet.  So you would want to `insert ... where not exists` and afterwards extract the rowid.  Why select 1 instead of select *?  Select col or Select 1 is marginally more efficient than selecting every column, and you don't need more than one column when testing for existence. If you had many columns, say, and were executing the test for existence in a loop, that marginal improvement in efficiency could  add up to "real money" so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

For newcomers, with the introduction of the **Upsert feature, we can insert rows (if they exist or not) in one shot**. Consider the following SQLite table:

```
CREATE TABLE "Person" (
    "Id"    INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "Name"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("Id")
)
```

Note that the Id column has a Unique constraint and hence cannot be duplicated.

And assume the Person table has the rows:

```
Id Name
-- ----
1  John
2  Bill
```

Now consider the following upsert statements:

```
INSERT INTO Person(Id, Name) VALUES (2,'Mike') ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
INSERT INTO Person(Id, Name) VALUES (3,'Hans') ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

When these statements are executed, the excution will be *successful* and only 1 row (namely 'Hans') will be inserted. The significant part is the

```
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
```

clause and **it ignores any conflicts** ('Mike' above is not inserted since his Id already exists) with the Insert statement. Without it we would get a unique constraint error.

SQLite page for the upsert feature:

https://www.sqlite.org/draft/lang_UPSERT.html

C# sample:

```
    public void Upsert()
    {
        string dbFilePath = "Test.db";
        string connectionString = $"Data Source={dbFilePath}";
        using (var connection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = $"INSERT INTO Person(Id, Name) VALUES(2, 'Mike') ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;";
                int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery(); // is 0
                System.Console.WriteLine("rowsAffected: " + rowsAffected);
            }
        }
    }
```

Note that I used the Microsoft.Data.Sqlite library (not System.Data.Sqlite) in the C# sample.